# Same url for all pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I'm working on a proyect in JSP, but i want to show in the navigator bar the same url for all the pages in my proyect.

I know how to do it with iframes and frameset, but I'm looking for a way to do it with javascript/ajax.

Can someone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do this?  it's pretty frustrating for anyone who knows what a URL is (including bookmarks, search engines, etc.), and it won't matter for anyone who doesn't

Comment: A guess SEO is a non-issue? Same with bookmarking?

Comment: if you do look at, jquery and its ajax function's

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking at, but it could serve to do [Servlet forward](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/forwarding-from-servlet-jsp) instead of redirect. Also refer to: [Forward vs redirect](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right. If you don't want the user to see the new addresses of the pages, you can use forward(request, response) to achieve that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Single page web apps where all page changes are done via AJAX are certainly possible, and are actually gaining popularity with frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). The exact implementation is going to vary wildly based on the nature of your project, so there isn't really much to say without more specific information.

As the simplest example I can think of, you could just have a link on your page run the following javascript (with jQuery) to completely reload the body of the page:

```
$("body").load("/path/to/new/body.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a page that will update the HTML DOM using Ajax.

The main page: foo.com/bar

```
<div id='ajax_container'>

</div>
```

Then in you JS, for specific user action (click in a menu...):

```
$(function(){
  $('#baz').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "foo.com/bazzz",
     cache: false
    }).done(function(html) {
      $("#ajax_container").append(html);
    });
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch condition in  the same  servlet .